# Not able to update after creating in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, memory, crud

In a nextjs tutorial, instead of creating and updating invoices from a db, I created a placeholder-data.js (in memory) to work locally. For some reason, after creating an invoice, it is not able to find the same invoice to update.

I logged to see the invoices after creating and updating, looks like it is working with 2 difference copies of invoices. The UI is sourcing from the copy in **createInvoice()** so it works fine, but **updateInvoice()** update its own copy of invoices.

```
'use server';

import { z } from 'zod';
import { invoices } from './placeholder-data';
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { fetchInvoiceById } from './data';

const FormSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  customerId: z.string(),
  amount: z.coerce.number(),
  status: z.enum(['pending', 'paid']),
  date: z.string(),
});

const CreateInvoice = FormSchema.omit({ id: true, date: true });  
export async function createInvoice(formData: FormData) {
    const { customerId, amount, status } = CreateInvoice.parse({
        customerId: formData.get('customerId'),
        amount: formData.get('amount'),
        status: formData.get('status'),
    });
    const amountInCents = amount * 100;
    const date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

    const newInvoice = {
        id: invoices.length.toString(),
        customer_id: customerId,
        amount: amountInCents,
        status: status,
        date: date,
      };
    invoices.push(newInvoice);
    console.log('Invoices in Component:', invoices);

    revalidatePath('/dashboard/invoices');
    console.log('Invoice created successfully!');
    redirect('/dashboard/invoices');
    // If you're working with forms that have many fields, you may want to consider using the entries() method with JavaScript's Object.fromEntries()
}


// Use Zod to update the expected types
const UpdateInvoice = FormSchema.omit({ id: true, date: true });
 
export async function updateInvoice(id: string, formData: FormData) {
  const { customerId, amount, status } = UpdateInvoice.parse({
    customerId: formData.get('customerId'),
    amount: formData.get('amount'),
    status: formData.get('status'),
  });

  const amountInCents = amount * 100;

  let fetchedInvoiceIndex = invoices.findIndex((inv) => inv.id === id);
  if (fetchedInvoiceIndex !== -1) {
    // Update the properties directly in the original invoices array
    invoices[fetchedInvoiceIndex].customer_id = customerId;
    invoices[fetchedInvoiceIndex].amount = amount;
    invoices[fetchedInvoiceIndex].status = status;

    console.log('Invoices in Component:', invoices);


    revalidatePath('/dashboard/invoices');
    redirect('/dashboard/invoices');
  } else {
    console.error('Invoice not found');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you link the tutorial? Redirecting to another page after manipulating an imported object like that *shouldn't* work, especially when running Next as a prod build. Can you use a proper database instead?

Comment: @Chris https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/mutating-data

I didn't want to use the DB, and just wanted to test out the crud fundamental. Then I encounter this issue. I think nextjs loads the placeholder-data.js in memory this way.

Redirecting after creating invoice works, its just the updateInvoice() updates a different invoices array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The log in createInvoices() shows a different invoices array than the log in updateInvoices.